# issue with this when two classes in one function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have two classes in a function and for some reason in the second function `this` is not being recognised correctly.

The classes are `Emitter` and `Receiver`.

I am trying to figure out why `this` is not being picked up correctly here. The log is included in the code below:

```
const chat = (messages) => {
  class Emitter {
    constructor(messages = []) {
      this.messages = messages;
      this.event = () => {};
    }

    setEvent(fn) {
      this.event = fn;
    }

    trigger() {
      this.messages.forEach(message => this.event(message));
    }
  }

  class Receiver {
    constructor() {
      this.messages = [];
      // this prints correctly here
      ---> Receiver { messages: [] }
      console.log('this  ===> ', this)
    }

    ping(message) {
      console.log('this ===>', this)
      // this here prints the following
      this ===> Emitter {
        messages: [ 'Hi', 'Hola', 'Bonjour', 'Hi' ],
        event: [Function: ping] }
          this.messages.push(message);
       }
  }

  const myReceiver = new Receiver();
  const myEmitter = new Emitter(messages);

  myEmitter.setEvent(myReceiver.ping);
  myEmitter.trigger();

  return myReceiver.messages;
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `this` depends on the scope where it is called but not the scope it is defined. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
In the call  myEmitter.setEvent(myReceiver.ping), only the function ping is passed to the myEmitter, not its scope myReciever. In case if you would like to pass myRevciever scope you can bind it the function call.

```js
myEmitter.setEvent(myReceiver.ping.bind(myReceiver));
```

Comment: Just adding on to this answer: one common practice is to bind the class methods in the constructor.

Comment: It's not correct to call the object "scope". You can it "target" or "receiver".